# How to add flutter packages to pubspec.yaml automatically in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-shortcuts, pubspec.yaml

How do I flutter packages to the pubspec.yaml file without going directly to the pubspec.yaml file.

I want to be able to add packages without leaving the current page I am working on.

I have seen this done in several tutorials and I want to know how it is done.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways of doing auto import in vscode:

1. Setting up Pubspec assist in VScode
2. Using the terminal (this does not require any extension)

**1. To setup in Pubspec Assist vscode use the instructions below:**

1. Install Pubspec assist extension in Vscode
2. Then go to the command panel using the shortcut [Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows OR ⌘+Shift+P on Mac](without the '+')
3. On the text field type - Pubspec Assist: add/update dependencies
4. Enter the name of the package you want to find

**Nb:**

- You install multiple packages once by separating them with commas
  eg: bloc, provider, http
- You only need to go through process *2 to 5* whenever you need to install a package again

hope this helps

**2. To use Terminal**

- Go to the terminal and type: `flutter pub add <package name>`

eg: `flutter pub add bloc`

- To upgrade a package use: `flutter pub upgrade <package name><br>`

eg. `flutter pub upgrade bloc`

*this second method does not bring up a dialog but also does the same auto import*

Have a nice day